# How to call a function and pass in a variable?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, return-value

I made a function that loops through the array 'bears' and logs all the names. 
How do I call the bearFunction and then pass in the 'bears' variable from A) so I can set the inner HTML to `<p>A paragraph about bears</p>` to the return value of the function at C)?

```
A)
const bears = [
    {
      name: "Steve",
      age: 25
    },
    {
      name: "Bob"
    },
    {
      name: "Peter",
      age: 6
    }
  ];
```

```
B)
function bearFunction(bearArray) {
    let bearDetails;
    for (let i = 0; i < bearArray.length; i++) {
      const bearNames = "<h2>" + bearArray[i].name + "</h2>";
      console.log(bearNames);
    }
  }
  bearFunction(bears);
```

```
C)
 bearFunction(bears);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You'll need to get the element you want to change. Look at [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

So first, C would need a different name:  `theOtherBearFunction(bear)` and you should be able to just pass that item to it in your for loop. Something like:

```
for (let i = 0; i < bearArray.length; i++) {
      const catNames = "<h2>" + bearArray[i].name + "</h2>";
      console.log(bearNames);
      theOtherBearFunction(bearArray[i].name);
    }
```

Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Thank you! But say I have already assigned a variable called 'container' and set the inner HTML to be <p>some random paragraph here</p>, how do I go about adding that value as the return value of the function?

Comment: Uh, i'm a little confused, but if i understand you correctly, you can return the innerHTML itself:   `return HTMLElementObject.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  For one thing, your written question is different than your sample code.  map() is a newer, more-advanced, more-concise way to do something to all of the elements of an array.  (It's reasonable to learn the for loop first).

```
const bears = [
    {
      name: "Steve",
      age: 25
    },
    {
      name: "Bob"
    },
    {
      name: "Peter",
      age: 6
    }
];

let catNames = bears.map(bear => `<p>${bear.name}</p>`);

console.log(catNames);
```